# Sonar raises blocker issue on java FileSystems.getDefault()

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have this below code statement,

```
this.watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
```

Sonar(**sonarqube 5.6.4**) raises a blocker issue in the **FileSystems.getDefault()** part of the above code, stating this,

> Resources should be closed - Java's garbage collection cannot be
>   relied on to clean up everything. Specifically, connections, streams,
>   files and other classes that implement the Closeable interface or it's
>   super-interface, AutoCloseable, must be manually closed after
>   creation. Failure to do so will result in a resource leak which could
>   bring first the application and then perhaps the box it's on to their
>   knees.

And then, i checked the javadoc for **FileSystem** which says,

> File systems created by the default provider cannot be closed.

Reference -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html

Now my problem is how to solve this sonar issue, without marking it ignore. 
Please help if anyone has solved this.

Comment: Which version of SonarJava analyzer are you using? This should work in recent version. You can update SonarJava analyzer in update center of your SonarQube

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do if you're sure of your case is to tell Sonar that what you have here is a false positive and that it should not be flagged.
You might also be able to use a try with resources construct, making Sonar think the resource is being closed when in fact it is not (if Java handles it correctly, it shouldn't try to close it when using a try with resources in this case).

Comment: try-with-resources won't work, default filesystem will throw `UnsupportedOperationException` . Flagging this as an FP is a way to go

Comment: I created a JIRA ticket on SonarJava analyzer to fix this false-positive https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2343

Comment: right @TiborBlenessy , try with resources will not solve it.

Comment: false positive is the only way to go.